# CORS is not enabling in django backend?

Tags: django, ionic-framework, cors, middleware

I'm trying to enable CORS for my django project which is interacting with ionic on frontend.When i send a post request to django backend, browser shows following error message:-

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/customer. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

While console shows `options` request method instead of `Post` .I enabled my custom middleware for handling CORS which is:-

```
class CorsMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
        return response
```

But it still keeps showing same error.My ionic server is running at `http://127.0.0.1:8100` while django backend is running on `http://127.0.0.1:3000`

Comment: have you added django-cors-headers? (https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers)

Comment: @user6837382 it's my cutom middleware , i don't think i need to include any package for it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue some time ago for me it fixed it when adding that in the Django api in `settings.py`

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://localhost:8200',
    'http://localhost:8100',
]
```

So you just add the two ionic localhosts in your case `http://127.0.0.1:8100`

Comment: i'm not using any package, it's my custom middleware.With this setting too, error still persists